# Compare 2 string array elements and return

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am actually an SQL developer but now working on C# and LINQ. I have a logic in my mind but due to technical barrier I am not able to implement it.

I will have 2 string array. And below are the conditions I want to implement,

1. I want to find if array 2 elements are present in array 1.
2. Then check sequence of elements of both the arrays.

For ex.
**Correct case**

string 1: `{"ID","Name","Age","Address","Gender","Phone"}`

string 2: `{"ID","Name","Phone"}`

So this should return **true**, as all array 2 elements are present in array 1 and sequence is also correct.

**Wrong Case**

string 1: `{"ID","Name","Age","Address","Gender","Phone"}`

string 2: `{"ID","Name","Phone","Address"}`

This should return false, although array 2 elements are present in array 1, "Phone" is appears before "Address", but in array 1 "Address" comes before "Phone". Sequence is incorrect so it should return false.

Is this possible? I haven't wrote any code as I am completely new to LINQ. Just quide me if this is possible in C# if not LINQ,

Comment: Could the first or second arrays have duplicates?

Comment: You have shown two examples where all members of the second array are present in the first array. Is it possible that some elements of the second array are not present in the first array?

Comment: No duplicates sir, @OJRaqueño

Comment: @Zhrez do you mean that you will need to check for duplicates, or that you're certain duplicates are impossible?

Comment: Yes @Steve its possible. array 1 is like Parent. array 2 won't have any extra element which is not present in array 1. It can have equal or less.

Comment: Hello @john , yes surely. There won't be duplicate element within array 1 nor array 2.

Comment: OK then my answer will work for you. Sweeper's answer is good, too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` and `SequenceEqual`:

```
string[] a = new [] {"ID","Name","Age","Address","Gender","Phone"};
string[] b = new [] {"ID","Name","Phone"};
string[] c = new [] {"ID","Name","Phone","Address"};

Console.WriteLine(a.Intersect(b).SequenceEqual(b));
Console.WriteLine(a.Intersect(c).SequenceEqual(c));
```

`Intersect` will get elements that are present in both a and b, and then `SequenceEqual` will ensure that they are in the same order.

It's worth noting that `Intersect()` effectively calls `.Distinct()`, so it will only work if the lists contain unique elements only. Duplicate items in either list will be ignored by the `Intersect()`.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNolLe)

Comment: Ah! `Intersects`. This is way better than my solution.

Comment: Wow. Simple and sweet solution. Thank you brother. saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
var mapped = b.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(a, x));
if (!mapped.Contains(-1) && mapped.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(mapped)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Correct Case");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Case");
}
```

where `a` and `b` are array 1 and array 2 respectively. There might be more efficient solutions available.

The logic is quite simple, we select the index of each element of `b` in `a`. If one element in `b` is not in one, there will be a `-1` in the result. I also checked whether `mapped.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(mapped)`. If `b` has `a`'s elements in the same order, then the indices should be in ascending order.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Sweeper. Thank you for the time. :)